# Using find to locate files that haven't been modified since the last time it was 6 AM

Tags: bash, date, find

I want to have a cron job that deletes files that haven't been changed since the last time it was 6 AM. It might not be clear so here is an example:

- If it is 8 AM on Monday, I want to delete every file before 6 AM on the same day.
- But if it is 4 AM on Monday, I want to delete every file before 6 AM on Sunday.

It is why I can't just use

```
find /path/ -type f ! -newermt '06:00:00' -delete
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it's past 6 AM first and modify the argument to **-newermt** accordingly.

```
if (( $(date +%-H) < 6 )); then
  when='yesterday 6'
else
  when='6'
fi
find /path/ -type f ! -newermt "$when" -print
```

Comment: I'm sure we've had a similar question lately, but can't find it.